# ignore a case and apply templates

Tags: xslt

I've the below sample line of XML.

Case1:

```
  <para><content-style font-style="bold">1.54</content-style> For the purposes of this book, the only authorities that are strictly speaking decisive are cases decided by the Singapore courts and their predecessors, and the earlier binding decisions of the Privy Council. This relative freedom from authority has its good and bad points. On the minus side, there is often a penumbra of uncertainty surrounding a proposition based upon a foreign case; until our courts have actually accepted the proposition, it can only be treated as tentative. On the plus side, we are not bound to follow a case that is wrong in principle or weak in reasoning. Our courts are at liberty to develop and interpret the law in a manner that is suitable to Singapore&#x2019;s needs.<page num="17"/></para>
```

Case 2:

```
<para><page num="5"/><content-style font-style="bold">1.12</content-style> In the context of the PA, the term &#x2018;firm&#x2019; refers collectively to those who entered into partnership with one another and the name under which partners carry on their business (i.e. name of their partnership) is referred to as the
```

Case3:

```
<para><page num="5"/><content-style font-style="bold">1.12</content-style> In the context of the PA, the term &#x2018;firm&#x2019; refers collectively to those who entered into partnership with one another and the name under which partners carry on their business (i.e. name of their partnership) is referred to as the <page num="6"/>
```

and i'm using the below XSLT line to apply-templates.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::content-style[1] and self::content-style[1]/preceding::page)]"/>
```

here what i'm trying to achieve is, to apply templates to `para` content leaving the first `page` that is first child node of `para` preceded by `content-style` and apart from this, though there are any other `page` the template should work fine. but here in my case, the `page`, first child of `para` preceding `content-style` is also getting caught.

please let me know where am i going wrong.

here in the cases, the output for case one should be catching the `page` and in t he second case the `page` should not be caught and int he case 3, `page num="5"` should be ignored and `page num="6"` should be caught

Thanks

Comment: You want to leave the page *out* of your selection? Add a predicate: `[not(self::page)]`.

Comment: hi @helderdarocha, i want to ignore the `page` that comes between `para` and first `content-style` and apply-templates for the rest, i don't want to ignore other `page` in the content

Comment: You need to add more context to your example. Also, from your code `page` is not *between* `para` and `content-style`. It is a *child* of `para`, unless there is a typo and you forgot to close it. Show your full template and add a larger part of your XML code.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, now i've updated my Question with sample cases, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the criteria for **page** initially, your current condition to check for the first **content-style** is not going to work...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::content-style[1])]" />
```

This will be true for all **content-style** elements. The `[1]` condition in this case is not the position of the node within its parent, but relates to the node just selected, and will be evaluated for each **content-style** separately. Therefore, the above code simply won't do what you expect.

To test for equality of nodes, consider first setting a variable to hold the unique id of the first **content-style**

```
<xsl:variable name="content" select="generate-id(content-style[1])" />
```

Then, your **xsl:apply-templates** would initially look like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(generate-id() = $content)]" />
```

And to expand this to cope with the **page** element, check the first following **content-style** also does not have the same id..

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()
      [not(generate-id() = $content or self::page[generate-id(following-sibling::content-style[1]) = $content])]"/>
```

An alternative approach is also possible. Rather than actively select only the nodes you want, just select all nodes, but have template matches to exclude the nodes you don't want. Replace you **xsl:apply-tempates** with just this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

Then add the following two templates in your code:

```
<xsl:template match="content-style[not(preceding-sibling::content-style)]" />

<xsl:template match="page[following-sibling::content-style and not(preceding-sibling::content-style)]" />
```

Comment: Hi @TimC, this is not working as expected, may be mistake from my part, I've a ready demo [here](http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Yn/1), here in this case `page num="94"` is not shown up in the result. please let me know how can i fix this. Thanks

Comment: Looking at your demo, I can't see the use of `generate-id()` anywhere, which is what I used in my answer..... Anyway, I have amended the code in your demo. See http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Yn/2